# SASS for each interpolation error when export css in compressed mode

Tags: sass, gruntjs

I have a map declared like below

Map Definition

```
$color-array:(
            black:#4e4e4e,                                   
            blue:#0099cc,
            dark-blue:#14394e,
            green:#2ebc78,
            white:#ffffff,
            orange:#ed6a0e    
        );
```

and calling the same in for each loop to generate class for text color and background color like below

```
@each $color-name, $color-value in $color-array{
    .#{$color-name}{
        color: $color-value !important;
    }
    .bg-#{$color-name}{
        background: $color-value !important;
    }
}
```

I am using gruntjs for for compilation, when i set output style to compressed it gives below error

> You probably don't mean to use the color value `#000' in interpolation
>   here. It may end up represented as #000000, which will likely produce
>   invalid CSS. Always quote color names when using them as strings (for
>   example, "#000"). If you really want to use the color value here, use`
>   "" + $color-name'.
>
> Error: Invalid CSS after ".": expected class name, was "#000"
>           on line 25 of SCSS/_base.scss
>           from line 5 of scss/style.scss

But when i set output style to expanded it runs fine.

Comment: I've just run this using grunt-sass 1.1.0 and it worked fine so it doesn't seem to be an issue with your syntax. Which version of grunt sass are you using? Maybe try upgrading?

Comment: Thanks for reply, my current version of grunt is 0.4.5,  can you guide me to how to update grunt

Comment: i was thinking more upgrading your grunt-sass version, if you open your package.json can you tell me what sass version your running? I'll try and replicate

Answer (score 0):

In your colors array, change all the key double-quoted string keys and things should work.

```
$color-array:(
            "black":#4e4e4e,                                   
            "blue":#0099cc,
            "dark-blue":#14394e,
            "green":#2ebc78,
            "white":#ffffff,
            "orange":#ed6a0e    
        );
```

An alternative of changing the SCSS code would be to make sure the variable is a string like the error message mentioned

```
@each $color-name, $color-value in $color-array{
    .#{"" + $color-name}{
        color: $color-value !important;
    }
    .bg-#{"" + $color-name}{
        background: $color-value !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is in the var declaration. You must define with keys inside
" ".
Like this:

```
$color-array:(
 "black":#4e4e4e,                                   
 "blue":#0099cc,
 "dark-blue":#14394e,
 "green":#2ebc78,
 "white":#ffffff,
 "orange":#ed6a0e
);
```